# Wordpress on Docker swarm plugin issues?

Tags: wordpress, docker, wordpress-theming, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I run a WP in docker container with mysql with docker-compose. I put a volume on host machine and everything goes well. During my development I install some themes.

When I am going to deploy my configuration to docker swarm:
1. I create from my wp container an image and commit it to repository
2. I share a volume from the host machine to wp service with mysql db
However when I run it in swarm mode - my installed themes are not there.

```html
version: '3'

services:
   db:
     image: localhost:5000/db2
     volumes:
       - ./realsitermark_db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: localhost:5000/rw
     volumes:
            - ./engage/engage/:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/engage
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mounting your theme `engage` using:

`- ./engage/engage/:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/engage`.

To use uploads, mount the entire `wp-content` directory.